# How do I include jQuery in my js file without html

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I made a chrome extension where my popup button calls a script. The other script uses jQuery but I get an error saying jQuery is not defined.

My popup.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>HomAttendance</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 style="color:#E54E4E">Hom<span style="color:#4E97E5">Attendance</span></h1>
        <button type id="record" style="background-color:White"><h1 style="color:Black">Record Attendance</h1></button>
    </body>
    <script src="jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
</html>
```

My popup.js:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var login = document.getElementById('record');
  login.addEventListener('click', function() {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript({file: 'markStudents.js'});
  });
});
```

myScript.js:

```
var arrays = []
$.get('Attendance.txt', function(data){

    var splitted = data.split("\n"); // --> should return an array for each line 

    // Loop through all lines 
    for(var i = 0; i < splitted.length; i++) 
    {

        var line = splitted[i]; 

        // Now you could remove [ and ] from string  
        var removed = line.replace('[','').replace(']','');
        var refined = removed.replace(' ', '');

        // Now you can split all values by using , delimiter
        var values = refined.split(',');  
        var array = [];
        // Now you can iterate through all values and add them to your array
        for(var c = 0; c < values.length; c++) 
        {
            var value = values[c]; 
            array.push(value);
        }
        arrays.push(array);
    }
});
var present = arrays[0];
console.log(present);
var absent = arrays[1];
console.log(absent);

var user = present[0];
var pass = absent[0];
var loginField = document.getElementById('fieldAccount');
var passwordField = document.getElementById('fieldPassword');
loginField.value = user;
passwordField.value = pass;
var loginForm = document.getElementById('btn-enter-sign-in');
```

Is there any way to include my jquery.js in myScript.js?

[Console Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOshG.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just import jquery before you import popup.js

Like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>HomAttendance</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 style="color:#E54E4E">Hom<span style="color:#4E97E5">Attendance</span></h1>
        <button type id="record" style="background-color:White"><h1 style="color:Black">Record Attendance</h1></button>
    </body>
    <script src="jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
</html>
```

Inside Your popup.js, when you load markStudents.js which uses jQuery, you'd again have to load jQuery before same

Like this

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    var login = document.getElementById('record');
    login.addEventListener('click', function () {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { file: "jquery-3.4.1.min.js" }, function () {
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { file: "markStudents.js" });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: It worked for a second, but it doesn't work again. Now it says $ is not defined.

Comment: Check your console & see if you haven't misspelled or put a wrong path for your script

Comment: Well myScript.js isn't in the HTML file, only the popup.js and jquery. Everything seems to be spelled right.

Comment: If this html you shared is the only code you have, and both the script are correctly found on the root path, I don't see an issue, please share your complete console error screenshot for reference

Comment: I edited the post to have my other script and I attached a screen shot of the error

Comment: Updated the answer with the solution for same

Answer (score 0):

Just reorder your script tags and put jQuery before your popup.js. That way it will be loaded when you try to call it.

Answer (score 0):

yo can use this code to include another jquery file in your jquery:

```
$.getScript("file address");
```

like this:

```
$.getScript("/assets/pages/scripts/ui-blockui.min.js");
```